Error after fixing higher android SDK version
I was getting this error
The plugin firebase_auth requires a higher Android SDK version.                               
Fix this issue by adding the following to the file D:\flutter_learn\android\app\build.gradle: 
android {
    defaultConfig {                                                                             
        minSdkVersion 23                                                                          
   }                                                                                           
}

so i changed minSdk=23;
android {
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.flutter_learn"
        minSdk = 23 //flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdk = flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode = flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName = flutterVersionName
    }
}



**After that i am getting this error **
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone16k x86 64 in debug mode...
√ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install

adb: failed to install D:\flutter_learn\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-2]
Error launching application on sdk gphone16k x86 64.

i don't know why this is happening does anybody know why this is happening!!!!
I added these
enter image description here

Have you tried changing your targetSdk?

Inside defaultConfig for any value you do not need to assign using = just name value (minSdkVersion 23)
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.flutter_learn"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
}


Everything else in build.gradle file is assigned using = and i tried doing it this way and is still not working.
